# using south datamigration to change value in old records

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration

Previously I had a django model like this

```
class Review(models.Model):
    reviewdate=models.DateField(default=date.today)
    description=models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
```

I have some 500 records of Review in db.

I added a field to model

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator,MaxValueValidator

class Review(models.Model):
    reviewdate=models.DateField(default=date.today)
    description=models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    rating= models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)], default=5, help_text='integers 1 to 10')
```

I ran `python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto` successfully ,which created a `0002_auto__add_field_review_rating.py` file

Now, I need to do the datamigration for the existing records in db. Do I have to run

`python manage.py datamigration myapp somechanges`

and then implement the functions in the created `somechanges.py` ?   Since I have already defined in the new field `difficulty` a default value of 5, will that not be taken when migrate command is run? Do I have to explicitly set it in the `somechanges.py` functions?

Comment: Cannot you just test your migration locally and find out? This is the best way (in addition to asking someone more experienced) to find out, whether you have done it correctly (at least in the part you have doubts).

Comment: sorry ,it is the first time I am doing this..and I am not sure how to take a backup of db ..Can such a migration change be rolled back if something goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do a data migration for this case. As you have specified a default for your new field, that will be used when you apply the schema migration.

Use the following command to apply the migration:

```
./manage.py migrate myapp
```

See the [advanced changes](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part2.html#defaults) South tutorial for more information on default values for new fields.